Use of the axiom of dependent choice in a standard proof of the Radon–Nikodym theorem
In both this mathoverflow post and this paper, the set theory and logic specialist Robert Solovay indicated that the proof of Radon–Nikodym theorem he read in Halmos' measure theory book used the axiom of dependent choice. One can find the full proof with this "variational principle" idea for example on proofwiki. I am attaching the core part of Halmos' original exposition below, which constructs the Radon–Nikodym derivative desired. However, I cannot figure out how dependent choice is used.
Theorem. For a ($\sigma$-)finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and another finite measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\nu \ll \mu$, there exists a measurable function $f$, which is nonnegative and unique in $L^1$, such that $$\nu(E) = \int_Ef\,d\mu$$ for all $E \in \mathcal{S}$.
Core part of Halmos' proof. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the class of all nonnegative functions $f$, integrable with respect to $\mu$, such that $\int_E f\,d\mu \leq \nu(E)$ for every measurable set $E$, and write $$\alpha=\sup\biggl\{\int f\,d\mu : f \in \mathcal{K}\biggr\} \leq \nu(X) < \infty.$$ Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{K}$ such that $$\lim_n \int f_n \,d\mu = \alpha.$$ (I believe choosing a sequence that goes to the supremum here requires countable choice only.)
Fix a measurable set $E$ and $n$, and define $g_n$ by $$g_n(x) = \max\{f_1(x),\dotsc,f_n(x)\},$$ then $E$ may be written as a finite disjoint union of measurable sets $E_1 \cup \dotsb \cup E_n$, so that $g_n = f_j$ on each $E_j$. Therefore $$\int_E g_n \,d\mu = \sum_{j = 1}^n \int_{E_j} f_j \,d\mu \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \nu(E_j) = \nu(E).$$ If we write $f_0(x) = \sup_{n} f_n(x)$, then $g_n$ increases to $f_0$ pointwise. It follows now from monotone convergence theorem that $f_0 \in \mathcal{K}$ and $\int f_0 \,d\mu = \alpha$.

If the maximum is attained by two or more functions, then you will need to choose the sets $E_j$ if you want them disjoint.

I think dependent choice is used in the proof of Hahn decomposition, namely theorem A of section 29, when you pick the sequence $E_j$ (not the $E_j$ in your proof). Btw Solovay in a comment claims he had a proof that only uses $AC_\omega$ but presumably he lost it...

@newaccount I checked and agree that the proof of Hahn decomposition in Halmos' book uses dependent choice. And yes, in fact only countable choice is needed for the result. Please see the answer below for detail.

The proof of Hahn decomposition in Halmos' book uses dependent choice, and his proof of the Radon–Nikodym theorem relies on Hahn decomposition, as @newaccount has pointed in the comment. This method of proving the Radon–Nikodym theorem is common among many contemporary textbooks, such as Folland.
And hence I did some further research on my own. The use of DC can indeed be avoided, as stated in Neil Falkner’s American Mathematical Monthly article "Hahn’s Proof of the Hahn Decomposition Theorem, and Related Matters". The proof that Falkner gives in the article is based on Hahn’s original proof, which only relies on AC_omega.
I am a little suspicious that the alternative proof of Radon–Nikodym that Solovay saw might be the proof based on Riesz representation theroem for Hilbert spaces, which is a standard alternative proof for authors that choose to present Hilbert spaces first. This proof can be found for example in Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis and Luigi Ambrosio, Giuseppe Prato, and Andrea Mennucci’s Introduction to Measure Theory and Integration.
However, now there is an extension question not directly related to Radon–Nikodym. Both books I mentioned above first define the total variation measure $\lvert \mu \rvert$ of a signed measure $\mu$ by $$\lvert\mu\rvert (E) = \sup\biggl\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert\mu(E_k)\rvert : \{E_k\} \text{ is a measurable partition of }E \biggr\}.$$ Then they both have to prove that the total variation norm $\lVert \mu\rVert = \lvert\mu\rvert(X)$ is finite. Here both books (Axler Theroem 9.17; Ambrosio et al. Proposition 6.20) again resort to an inductive construction based on dependent choice to show that $\lvert\mu\rvert(X) \neq \infty$. This means that for both books, the proof of Hahn–Jordan decomposition for signed measures again relies on DC. (To be specific, Axler proves Hahn decomposition first, relying on the result that the total variation norm is finite. He then defines the positive part $\mu^+$ and the negative part $\mu^-$ of a signed measure $\mu$ based on Hahn decomposition. Ambrosio et al., on the other hand, define $$\mu^+ = \frac{1}{2} (\lvert\mu\rvert + \mu) \quad \text{and} \quad \mu^- = \frac{1}{2} (\lvert \mu \rvert - \mu)$$ first, and this requires first proving that the total variation norm is finite. They then prove that this decomposition into $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ of signed measure corresponds to a Hahn decomposition on $X$. I think this is also the way Rudin presents, in Chapter 6 of his Real and Complex Analysis.)
This poses a natural question: is it possible to avoid dependent choice again when we prove $\lvert\mu\rvert(X) < \infty$, under the definition of total variation measure $\lvert \mu \rvert$ given above? I have a feeling that this could be a challenging question.
